# TimeMachine shows a sea of nothingness when I select Mail

Tags: time-machine, catalina

1. I select Mail
2. I open time machine
3. it shows this:

[image]

You see? Nothing, no message. There is nothing on the timeline. Timeline does not offer anything to click. You click and it goes nowhere.

I have used this functionality in the Mojave, but this does not work on Catalina.

Before suggesting me to fiddle on the Time Machine directories to restore all my mails, know that I do not want to restore one trillion emails to restore the one email that I have deleted and am trying to recover.

I just want this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Hover your cursor over the 'scale' on the right. Dates with backups should look less transparent than ones without. Quick example on a brand new TM backup, showing where it runs out… [red is the one that will be selected if you click, which I avoided for this pic.] https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNzHt.png

Comment: like I said, nothing is clickable there.

Comment: Does TM work correctly when restoring files in the Finder? Have you excluded any folders?

Comment: yes, works perfectly. Are you able to make it work on your computer using catalina?

Comment: I don't have a Catalina Mac that's using TM. However, there do seem to be a variety of reports of problems with Mail and TM over Catalina's lifespan.

Comment: thanks. It seems that this is another bug.